# Error when show site map page

Tags: laravel, sitemap

I make laravel aplication by version 4.2 and use [RoumenDamianoff/laravel](https://github.com/RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap)-sitemap package for Generate Sitemap.
I have problem . when generate and show sitemap in browser show this error:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of >the document
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I'm sorry for bad English
thanks